# Invalid char like "&","?" using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

Ok guys, i've this:

```
<textarea class="boxCommento1" placeholder="Scrivi un commento.."></textarea>
<input style="width:100%;" type="button" value="Inserisci" onclick="functionThatObtainTextFromTextarea();"/>
```

When i click on the input button i get the text form the textarea, and i will insert that in my DB using PHP and AJAX, but there's a problem if i write something like this: "What did u do yesterday???" or char like this "&" when i'll get text using php, "?" and "&" won't be recognized of course, because using GET and POST "?" and "&" are used for php url variables... any advice???

PS: Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in the AJAX Javascript.

When you get the variable in PHP with `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`, it'll [automatically be decoded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php), so you don't need to do anything else.

```
//Javascript
var inserisciValue = encodeURIComponent(theInsertisciValue);
```

Comment: $_REQUEST and $_GET are already urldecoded by php, see the big red note on the man page ->  http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: @Crisp doh, I've been doing it wrong then! I've updated my answer. Now to update all my code...

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to save lots of time